# Cannot open database [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server] using python

Tags: python, sql-server, odbc, driver, pyodbc

I got the following error ,[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Login failed for (); [] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Cannot open database "xxxxx" requested by the login. The login failed. ()').

i have tried all the combinations. I have also checked the version of ODBC driver ( 13 odbc and 17 odbc with 64bytes)  and python supportive with 64 bytes.

```
    conn_str = (
        'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server};'
        'SERVER=xxxxx;'
        'DATABASE=xxxxx;' 
        'Trusted_Connection=yes;'
        'username = xxxx;'
        'password = psswrd;' 
    )
    cxn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
```

Comment: Are both the SQL Server instance and your Python code running under Windows?

Comment: Yea .I am using Windows .

Comment: Try using `Trusted_Connection=no` and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: I tried that , there was no difference. Not sure how to debug this issue